# Installing service using SC/ service control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I had a windows service installed on my computer. I deleted it with

```
sc delete myservice
```

Then I recreated it with

```
sc create collector binpath = "path of service"
```

but service is not listed under services in control panel.

I tried to recreate the service and got:

```
[SC] CreateService FAILED 1073:
```

The specified service already exists.

I am trying to delete the service and getting:

```
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:
```

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

What is causing the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: can you post your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [installutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead, this fixed similar problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've had issues like that installing/uninstalling services before and often I found that I had the Services MMC open while trying command line operations. Closing it out and attempting the install/uninstall again has worked for me in the past. Not sure if that will aid you but it's something that's helped me many times.